# How to Block a Domainname with random TLDs in Postfix?

Tags: postfix, spam, wildcard, block, tld

Can anyone please tell me how to reject all domains with a particular name, but regardless of the TLD? I want to block all mail coming from domains named `bulksender`, like `bulksender.com`, `bulksender.org`, `bulksender.biz`, `bulksender.vn` etc.

I have a postmap file `client_checks.postmap` which i have included in `main.cf` like this:

```
check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_checks.postmap
```

In that file I´ve tried:

```
bulksender. REJECT 550 5.1.0 Go away!
```

But it did not work.

Is there something like `*@bulksender.*` which would block all domains named bulksender, regardless which TLD Ending they have?

Answer (score 2):

Postfix with [PCRE support](http://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html) allows regular expressions on sender address verification.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

I've [used](https://blocked.icu/) it to block entire TLDs

```
/\.icu$/ 554 https://blocked.icu/
```

but it should fit your requirements, too:

```
/@bulksender\./ 554 Go away!

/\100bulksender\./ 554 Go away!
```

To include all subdomains of these domains:

```
/@.*\.?bulksender\./ 554 Go away!
```

Notice that `check_sender_access` makes this a [sender restriction](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions), but I intentionally use it in [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) making it fire only after a full set of `HELO`, `MAIL FROM` and `RCPT TO` commands. This way the logs won't be lacking information on the recipients, in case something goes wrong.

The `check_client_access` doesn't check email addresses, but the [client](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_restrictions) connecting to your SMTP server:

> ```
> check_sender_access type:table
> ```
>
> Search the specified [access(5)](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) database for the `MAIL FROM`
>   address, domain, parent domains, or `localpart@,` and execute the
>   corresponding action.
>
> ```
> check_client_access type:table
> ```
>
> Search the specified access database for the client hostname, parent
>   domains, client IP address, or networks obtained by stripping least
>   significant octets. See the [access(5)](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) manual page for details.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help! This looks good indeed. However i tried various regex pcre testers online and all said that this is not matching:

/@bulksender./ 554 Go away!

/\100bulksender./ 554 Go away!

Are you sure these block *@*.bulksender.* ?

Daniel

Comment: Hi Esa - naw.. i want to block all bulksender.* Domains. The sender registers lets say .COM, .ORG, .INFO Domains and i want to block all of them. So i want to block *@bulksender.* OR even *@*.bulksender.* (because they sometimes have a mailserver prefix like sender@mailserver1234.bulksender.com and sender@anotherserver.bulksender.nl (these are only examples of course)

Comment: That's not what you originally asked, but then `/@.*\.?example\./` should do it without matching the `example` in username part i.e. before the `@`.

Comment: Hi Esa. Thanks for the help. This worked. KR - Daniel